How turbo engines increase efficiency if have lower compression ratio than naturally aspirated engines?
I know that efficiency depends on compression ratio(CR), NA engines always has higher CR than turbos,so how turbo engine can have better thermal efficiency?
Please explain using Otto cycle, how temperature T1,T2,T3,T4 are different at turbo vs NA engine.



Study the difference between naturally aspirated engines and forced air from a turbo or super charger, creating positive pressures in the intake system.

From the edit: I would leave the blue/green lines out from the diagram, since when the air is pushed out, its volume doesn't go to zero (it goes to the atmosphere), and when new air is taken in, it doesn't start from zero volume. The exchange of intake/exhaust gases isn't relevant to the thermodynamic cycle which is adequately described by (1,2,3,4) -- the 0 is an unnecessary point.

I think the basic point being missed here is what propels a turbocharger ... heat energy from the exhaust. Use any part of the heat being wasted through the exhaust and you're seeing increased efficiency.
For reference, the following figure denotes typical losses in an ICE:

33% of the losses go out the exhaust. Since the turbo uses heat from the exhaust to power the turbine, using it garners you efficiencies.
As for compression ratio and how it lends to power output and thermal efficiency, it is said as a rule of thumb that 1 point of static compression ratio provides about 3% increase in power. The opposite of that is true, also (ie: reducing CR reduces power output). The reason why most turbocharged engines have a reduced CR is to help prevent pre-detonation, pinging, or knock. While reducing the CR also reduces the power, the lower CR allows for a greater air/fuel charge, thus increasing the power output. In general speak, for every atmosphere of air you stuff into your engine, you will gain 100% horsepower (ie: boosting to 14.7psi [or 1 bar] into an engine which produced 300hp naturally aspirated will theoretically produce 600hp). While this figure isn't exactly correct (you have some mechanical and other losses), you can use it to give you a very good ballpark figure of an engine's output under boost. And yes, to make this happen, you do use more fuel, the basics of it is, using the exhaust heat to spin the turbine will increase efficiencies because of that use.

@paulster2 this graph is wrong, aero drag is by far biggiest loss

@22flower - You have any proof of that assertion? I didn't just pull this out of the nether regions.

https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTjAGylIu2HKaNgiaajIqlwmo4abns8lB800wHeFL4YWKJqhm1Xta9ftauFooo3OJZh2yM&usqp=CAU      https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267776699/figure/fig1/AS:295684407349267@1447508064302/Increase-in-Aerodynamic-Drag-with-increase-in-Speed-Consider-a-vehicle-having-frontal.png

@22flower - You'll also notice the figure I posted doesn't show speed of the vehicle. I believe the figures you've shown shows rolling resistance and air drag to be equal at about 55mph. This will also be different by the size of vehicle and it's cross section. Yes, air drag increases as speed increases. This doesn't negate what I'm trying to say about how turbos increase efficiency.

I sort-of get what OP is saying. The rolling resistance and air drag have nothing to do with the efficiency of the engine, any more than the road's gradient, or the gross weight. They are a common factor of the vehicles and running conditions, not of their engines.

@WeatherVane - The only "real" reason for showing the graph I did was to show how much energy goes out the tailpipe ... 1/3 of it. If you can steal some of that heat, you'll gain efficiency.

Yeah, I gave UV..

@WeatherVane - I figured as much and do appreciate.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 why nobody talk about higher effective compression ratio in turbo engine?

@22flower - I don't really know, but would assume its because of the math involved. It is easy to figure out the how much boost the turbo is putting out and figuring out how much benefit you might be getting from it, versus everything involved when figuring the dynamic compression ratio while the engine is under boost. It would take some higher level calculus in order to come to an understanding.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 Please explain using Otto cycle, how temperature T1,T2,T3,T4 are different at turbo vs NA engine.

@22flower - Two things: 1) No clue what temps you're talking about; 2) Prolonged conversations are not what comments are for. If you'd like to know more, either start a chat thread or ask a new question. Either way, explain what you're talking about so everyone can clue in. Thank you.

@Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 temperatures at point 1,2,3,4 at otto cycle, see my graph

I think this is due to something not considered by the ideal model.
The ideal model considers only thermodynamics, not real-life effects like friction or pumping losses.
A turbo engine of the same size produces more power, so an engine of the same power would be smaller. This means less friction and less pumping losses, since the engine operates with a throttle that is more open.
Note that with CR 13, you get about 63% thermal efficiency according to your chart. No real car gasoline engine has this efficiency. Toyota's most efficient hybrid engines have maximum 41% thermal efficiency.
This is due to friction, which your ideal model doesn't consider.
Large ship engines built by Wärtsilä achieve 50% thermal efficiency. Wärtsilä RTA96-C for example is turbocharged, by the way, but it's a two-stroke diesel and rotates much slower than car engines.

Note that big two stroke engines requires blowers to provide air.

@juhist toyota has 41% only with engine or with electric motor included?

@22flower It's only for the engine. Remember that electric motor in non-plug-in hybrids provides only power that has been charged by the engine itself anyway. Toyota hybrids are pure gasoline cars, where the job of the electric motor is make the engine run less often, and when the engine runs, it runs very close to the optimal operating point, i.e. closer to 41%. In regular cars, typical operating point efficiency is only 25% since they operate so far away from the engine optimal operating point.

@juhist how they achieve 41% only from engine itself? so this is bigger then turbo engines?

@22flower Turbo isn't the only thing that increases engine efficiency. Atkinson cycle is something else. I guess a good modern turbo engine could get close to 41% too.
